# Postgres cache select distinct on sub query for speedup

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query and a subquery. The subquery filters out similar entries, but it is mostly the same. There are 3 or 4 different ones that will be used, but they will be reused quite often. The subquery is very slow and takes multiple seconds. Is there a way to cache the result of the subquery so the subquery will not have to be executed every time?

This query is different every time
Query:

```
SELECT * FROM {subquery} ORDER BY id LIMIT 10;
```

The ... in the subquery will differ in a limited amount of variation(3or4 different variations that can be used here). It will contain joins and order by like and =. It will query both tables completely.
subquery:

```
(SELECT DISTINCT ON ...) p
```

Comment: Use a temporary table or a materialized view.

Comment: Thank you materialized view is what I was looking for. It’s basically caching